# Редактирование заказа покупателем после оформления

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

Клиенту для сайта требуется реализовать возможность редактирования заказа после оформления. А именно, пока заказ имеет статус, к примеру, "На удержании" (который я поставил по умолчанию для всех видов оплаты), покупатель может зайти в личный кабинет и добавить либо убрать какой-то товар к заказу. Такой вот нестандартный функционал. Как я понял по поиску в Гугле, такое ещё никто не реализовывал. 
Подскажите, куда копать, пожалуйста.

Comment: А что именно вы хотите редактировать? Как я понял админ может только кол-во менять или удалить товар, даже добавить не может)

Comment: @WP Punk Админ может в админке как угодно заказ редактировать. Мне нужно, чтобы покупатель в личном кабинете мог как-то свои "незакрытые" заказы редактировать.

Comment: В целом в профиле, где у пользователя его заказы, вы можете это как-то редактировать. На бекенде в WC_Order уже есть все нужные методы, но над интерфейсом нужно подумать

Comment: @WP Punk "Из коробки" такого функционала нет. Вот я и думаю, с чего начать, к каким хукам цепляться и т.д. Если бы уже кто-то такое делал...

Comment: @АртёмСвистула в то время как менеджер собирает заказ - клиент оба на и всё поменял? Серьёзно хочется этого геммора? Вопрос риторический, для подумать над логикой процессов обработки заказов.

Comment: SeVlad Хочется не мне, а заказчику. Да и геморроя, как такового, будет немного.